Nuxt 3 App doesnt minimize JS files in production
I have a production Nuxt 3 app deployed on Vercel and it's not minifying and combining the JS files as I'd expect it to. Some observations:

In the nuxt.config.ts the ssr is set to false so it's a SPA.
In the vercel project dashboard I don't have any commands configured for deployment, it autodetects the app and deploys it automatically.
Ran yarn build locally and checked the contents of .output/public and it just had some stray JS files and didnt contain the bulk of the JS files that I see being requested when I load a page in production. I tried adding this based on a suggestion from ChatGPT but it didn't help:

  vite: {
    build: {
      terserOptions: {
        compress: {
          drop_console: true,
        },
        mangle: {
          properties: {
            regex: /^_/
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

Here's the complete Nuxt config stripped of irrelevant detail:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
    }
  },
  vite: {
    build: {
      terserOptions: {
        compress: {
          drop_console: true,
        },
        mangle: {
          properties: {
            regex: /^_/
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  app: {
    pageTransition: { name: 'page', mode: 'out-in' },
    buildAssetsDir: 'assets',
    head: {
      meta: [
      ],
      link: [
      ],
      script: [
      ],
    }
  },
  ssr: false,
  css: ['~/assets/css/main.css'],
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vercel.ts', mode: 'client' },
  ],
  modules: [
    // pinia plugin
  ],
  pwa: {
    meta: {
    },
    manifest: {
    }
  },
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
  components: [
    { path: '~/components/tutorial/', },
   '~/components'
  ]
})

